# How to add different titles to each element of CheckedMultiSelect?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, dojo

I am trying to add title to each checkbox in `CheckedMultiSelect`.

Code for creating `CheckedMultiSelect`:

```
<select id="123" class="soria" dojoType="dojox.form.CheckedMultiSelect" 
        multiple="true" style="width:267px; height:260px;" onchange=""
        store="listStore">
</select>
```

`listStore` is a `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore` from json.

Any ideas how to add title to checkbox?

**UPD.** On finally I received the HTML code like this(source code fore single element of multiselect):

```
<div aria-selected="false" widgetid="dojox_form__CheckedMultiSelectItem_4"
     id="dojox_form__CheckedMultiSelectItem_4" 
     class="dijitReset dojoxMultiSelectItem">

      <div widgetid="dijit_form_CheckBox_4" role="presentation" 
            class="dijitReset dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemBox dijitCheckBox" 
            wairole="presentation">

        <input aria-pressed="false" style="-moz-user-select: none;" 
        tabindex="0" id="dijit_form_CheckBox_4" value="on" 
        class="dijitReset dijitCheckBoxInput" dojoattachpoint="focusNode"
        dojoattachevent="onmouseover:_onMouse,onmouseout:
                         _onMouse,onclick:_onClick" 
        type="checkbox">

      </div>

      <div class="dijitInline dojoxMultiSelectItemLabel" 
            dojoattachpoint="labelNode" dojoattachevent="onmousedown:_onMouse,
                    onmouseover:_onMouse,onmouseout:_onMouse, onclick:_onClick">
            MICHAEL, DOPHINE
      </div>
</div>
```

Question: how I can point the dojo to set unique title for this element?

Comment: What do you mean by "title"? The `title=""` attribute?

Comment: yes, I should add different title="" attribute to each checkbox

Comment: I'm still not sure what your problem is. Can't you just add the `title` attribute to your `<select>`?

Comment: The problem that I need to add different titles to each checkbox which will created on page.

Comment: @oleksii The OP commented just before you, making that clear, but thank you nonetheless.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a script that changes the titles afterwards like

```
<script>
var o = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for(var x in o){
   // check if o[x].name is one of these and then
   // do something with o[x].title ...
}
</script>
```